# Error when using Kafka console Producer from Host outside of Cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka

I have a Hortonworks Hadoop Cluster and everything seems to work fine. I can use the Kafka Producer and the consumer from all the Hosts, that reside inside of that cluster.

But when i try to use the kafka console producer from another host i get the following error message:

> ERROR Error when sending message to topic test with key: null, value: 0 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
>   Org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for test-0: 1532 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time

I can Telnet the Host and Port.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Try to see what happend in Kafka using DEBUG or even TRACE log level
<Logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="DEBUG" additivity="false"><AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/></Logger>